# Make single ADO stage only in a build completion triggered pipeline depend on the trigger being pulled

Tags: azure-devops

I have 2 Azure DevOps pipelines the second triggered by build completion of the first however I want one of the stages in the second pipeline to only execute if the current run is as a result of a build completion triggered run (and not if manually triggered). The rest of the stages can execute for either manual or build triggered executions. Is there a way to do this?

I am able to make the execution conditional upon the build being a scheduled build but not for build completion triggered build.

Comment: can you please share the YAML code as well?